# Convert Automatically Spaces to Tabs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file in Visual Studio Code in which I use only tabs for indentation. When I copy the contents of that file somewhere else and edit them, then when I paste them back all tabs are gone and spaces have taken their places.

How can I prevent the use of spaces for indentation and automatically spaces will be converted to tabs?

Also I have changed the preferences:

```
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't (yet). I think it would be nice to get spaces/tabs converted upon file opening - like some editors do. You can quickly convert spaces by tabs by selecting the number of indentation spaces, pressing cmd+F2 in mac or ctrl-F2 in linux/windows (to find and select all occurrences of that amount of spaces), and then pressing tab key (only once). You can also give Untabfy (or Whitespacer) a try.